# the same struct in array and mappings

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

Let's say I have a `struct`.

```js
struct test {
  uint x;
}

test[] all;
mappings(uint => test) map;

function bla(){
   test memory structTest = test(5);
   all.push(structTest);
   map[10] = structTest;
}
```

After the code, will `structTest` be saved in one place and then my array and map will save the references to it or it will be stored separately in map and array ?

If the latter, how can I create struct and store it in mapping and array so that I don't waste space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A copy of `structTest` is saved separately in the array and in the mapping.

In order to get rid of this redundancy, you can maintain an array of keys instead of values:

```
uint[] all; // instead of `test[] all;`
mappings (uint => test) map;

function bla() {
    test memory structTest = test(5);
    all.push(10); // instead of `all.push(structTest);`
    map[10] = structTest;
}
```